# Databricks -Test SQL created table exists with correct columns

Tags: unit-testing, databricks

I'm trying to create a test in Databricks that checks a suite of tables has been correctly created with the correct columns.  This feels as if it should be simple but I can't quite grasp the solution, everything is migrated from Oracle and my background is Oracle and SQL rather than python.

So for example, imagine the following example table that will be populated with dashboard data.  If it already exists with a different structure the reporting scripts will fail.

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $report_schema.p23a_com 
(AGE_GROUP                                STRING,
 UniqServReqID                            STRING,
 Rec_Code                                 STRING,
 Elapsed_days                             INT)
USING delta 
PARTITIONED BY (AGE_GROUP)
```

Part of the test is as follows but obviously the assert fails because of the partition column info.
I can't seem to make DESCRIBE less wordy, I could remove the # from the input list but that seems messy and makes it more difficult when I extend the test to pick up datatype. Is there a better way to capture the schema?

```
def get_table_schema(dbase,table_name):

    desc_query="DESCRIBE "+dbase+"."+table_name
    df_tab_cols = sqlContext.sql(desc_query)
    return df_tab_cols

def test_table_schema(tab_cols,list_tab_cols):

    input_col_list = df_tab_cols.select("col_name").rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()
    assert set(input_col_list) == set(list_tab_cols)

db = report_schema
table = "p23a_com"
cols = ["AGE_GROUP","UniqServReqID","Rec_Code","Elapsed_days"]

df_tab_cols = get_table_schema(db,table)

test_table_schema(df_tab_cols,cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is that we have migrated a reporting system to databricks and some builds are failing due to tables existing, old versions of tables, creates failing when drops haven't completed; we also don't have full git integration and some environments are more wild west than I would like.

As a result a schema check is necessary.

As I couldn't get an answer the following is my final code in case anyone else needs something similar. As I wanted to check columns and column types I switched to dictionaries, it turns out that comparing dictionaries is simple.

I don't think it is very pythonic and it isn't efficient when there are a lot of tables. I think the dictionary creation from a dataframe might need an rdd in non-databricks environments.

Feel free to critique as I am still learning.

```
# table_list is a python dictionary in the form 
# {tablename:{column1:column1_type, column2:column2_type, etc:etc}} 
# When a table is added or changed in the build it should be added as a dictionary item.

table_list = {
 'p23a_com': {'AGE_GROUP': 'string',
    'UniqServReqID': 'string',
    'Rec_Code': 'string',
    'Elapsed_days': 'int'},
 'p23b_com': {'AGE_GROUP': 'string',
    'UniqServReqID': 'string',
    'Org_code': 'string',
    'Elapsed_days': 'int'}}


# Function to get the schema for a table
# Function takes the database name and the table name and returns a dictionary of the columns and data types.

def get_table_schema(dbase,table_name):

    desc_query = dbase+"."+table_name   
    df_tab_cols = spark.createDataFrame(spark.table(desc_query).dtypes)
    tab_cols_dict = dict(map(lambda row: (row[0],row[1]), df_tab_cols.collect())) 
    return tab_cols_dict

# This is the test, it cycles through the table_list dictionary returning the columns and types and then doing a dictionary compare.
# The query will fail on any missing table or any table with incorrect columns.

for tab in table_list:

    tab_cols_d = get_table_schema(db,tab)
    assert tab_cols_d == table_list[tab]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is me being a bit thick and too SQL focused.  Instead of using SQL Describe all I needed to do was read the table directly into the dataframe via spark then use columns.

ie

```
def get_table_schema(dbase,table_name):

    desc_query = dbase+"."+table_name
    df_tab_cols = spark.table(desc_query)
    return df_tab_cols

def test_table_schema(tab_cols,list_tab_cols):

    input_col_list = list(df_tab_cols.columns) 
    assert set(input_col_list) == set(list_tab_cols)

    print(input_col_list)
```